# Delayed_job "Undefined method" in production. (Passenger, no RVM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I've seen this error pop up in other places, but my circumstances seem to be somewhat unique. I'm running `delayed_job` (2.1.4) on my production server, which is using `nginx`, `passenger`, `ruby 1.9.2`, and `rails 3.0.10`. It is **not** using RVM. My jobs were running fine until my last code deploy, and now they all fail, with this message in the log:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMailer 
object: !ruby/object:Class TemplateMailer
method_name: :send_email
#snip
{undefined method `send_email' for #<Class:0x00000007523e90>
```

I looked through similar answers here, and on [delayed_job's wiki](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems), but haven't been able to crack it.

Everything is running fine on a VM staging server that I set up, so what could the problem be in production?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have a `setup_load_paths.rb` in your config directory

Comment: It's not using rvm, so there is no setup_load_paths.rb on the server anywhere.